# Как можно сделать ProgressBar с непрерывно движущейся картинкой?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Как можно сделать *ProgressBar*, чтобы *Image* (картинка) непрерывно двигалась слева направо, постепенно исчезая справа и появляясь слева?

[image: пример картинки]

Comment: для справки: исправить свой вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу 2 пути:

1. Использовать 2 картинки которые ты двигаешь одновременно а потом правую картинку перемещаешь влево в нужный момент. Конечно же, скрывая то, что видеть пользователь не должен.
2. Использовать эфект оффсета(имеется ввиду эфект оффсет из стандартного набора фотошопа). То есть: Ты берешь самый правый столбец пикселей и переносишь ее на первый столбец(сдвигая другие вправо). Этот вариант, конечно же, лучше.

Детали реализации гугли сам :)